# Are there any performance downsides to share NSLock between Objective-C and Swift files?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, metal, metalkit

To put it simple, I use Metal to render textures at very high FPS. Just for simplicity reasons when following the metal examples from Apple, I wrote the renderer in Objective-C and bridge it over to my other Swift code which modifies the data coming in to the renderer. This works great but for now I just sync between the GPU and CPU using an NSLock in the renderer file and render to an OffscreenTexture (which I have to do anyway to save the changes). I could do all the code syncing to the GPU but I can't be certain that i finish all work in 16 ms (60fps) and I always want to retrieve the latest information from the server.

```
    
    if ([_writeLock tryLock]) {
        //render and return true from the commandBuffer upon completion + unlock
    } else {
        //return false
    }
```

However, this leads to unnecessary work on the Swift part. The easiest fix I could think of would be to share the NSLock (_writeLock) or somehow share a semaphore between Objective-C and swift (to only perform crucial parts when necessary). Or maybe it is enough to just call some Swift code in between renders from the renderer (when I know the GPU is not working)?

The main point of this question however is whether there are any performance downsides to having the renderer in Objective-C and bridging it over to the main Swift code and what limitations / cautions should be taken when calling code and sharing variables between them?

Comment: Swift-Objective-C interop doesn't really much have much overhead. Swiftt participates in the same Objective-C message passing as the rest of the code. There are some edge cases around how bridging of `NSString`s and `NSArray`s and such works, but those are all O(1) overheads IIRC.